Не получается корректно отобразить кодировку в расширении mustache
Не могу настроить отображение на кириллице файлов с расширением mustache через Spring boot
Вот файл мустач на который переводит контроллер по запросу /addexcel :
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Отправка файла на сервер</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>

    <form action="\logout" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Выйти"/>
    </form>

</div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

<h3>Добавьте файл для расчета статистики:</h3>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/getResult">
    <p><input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить"></p>
</form>
<div></div>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>

Вот  app properties:
spring.application.name=XLSX4
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.file-size-threshold=2KB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

Вот pom.xml:
modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>org.workproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>XLSX5</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>XLSX5</name>
    <description>XLSX parcer  project for Spring Boot</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>

    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6</artifactId>
            <!-- Temporary explicit version to fix Thymeleaf bug -->
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

Вот так отображается:


В итоге просто нужно было в браузере сместить вниз русский язык


Отображение налаживается лишь только когда меняешь язык самого браузера с русского на английский.  Но это я не считаю за решение.
